# Preventing non-admin users from reading connection string

Tags: .net, encryption, configuration-files

We are developing a WPF app that runs on a remote server. The users connect to the server via RDP and run the app from the remote desktop.

We want to prevent the (non-admin) users from connecting to the SQL Server directly. By default, connection strings to the (SQL Server) database are stored in the `app.config` file in plaintext. How can we prevent users from opening `app.config` and reading the connection information there?

I've read about using .NET's built-in facility for encrypting/decrypting parts of a configuration file ([Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), but I don't understand how much more secure this is. The app must have read-access to the encryption key in order to decrypt the connection string. If the app is running under the currently logged-in user's credentials, that means the user must also have read-access to the encryption key. What is to prevent the user from using the `ConfigurationManager` class (from LINQPad, or PowerShell) to access the connection info?

Alternatively, can I can setup the application to always run under a specified user, and give read-access to the encryption key to that user only?

Any suggestions and input will be most welcome.

Comment: Do you need to give users a full desktop on the remote server?  If not only give the users a desktop with the .exe (not even a cmd).  The .exe can read the config but user cannot get to it.

Comment: That kind of protection is implemented to make sure anybody but the legit user cannot read out the key; it is not implemented to protect it against the user itself.

Comment: @owlstead Is there any way to protect against the user?

Comment: I think the comment of Blam and the answer of NothingsImpossible are right on. You either restrict the runtime or you create different deterrents. If the users can run stuff in a full runtime environment you are basically trying to create a DRM scheme, which are known to fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about the users using such advanced techniques as LINQPad or Powershell to read the config file, there is really nothing that can be done aside from embedding the connection string inside the assembly and obfuscate it - and even this can be circumvented.

What you should do is get all the database logic and put it in a WebService, on a separate server - and modify the application to access the database via the WebService. If you did it The Right Way (TM) than it is easy as swapping the "Database Access Layer" with a "Service Access Layer". This way you can authenticate each one with a custom password, and then if someone plays around with it you will have a log of who did what and when.

Liability is a powerful deterrent.